# C# WPF DataGrid: DataGridComboxBoxColumn Binding ItemsSource failed

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

i want to display a `ComboBox` on my `DataGrid`. But the `ComboBox` does not load the `ObservableCollection`. My `ObservableCollection` 'Projects' is on my ViewModel defined. The problem is not the `DataContext`. But when I define the `ComboBox` outside of my `DataGrid`, the binding works. Does anyone have an idea where my problem is?

ViewModel:

```
public Project SelectedProject
{
    get { return _project; }
    set
    {
        if (_project != value)
        {
            _project = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            _actions = _database.LoadActions(SelectedProject.Id);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Actions);
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
{
    get { return _database.LoadProjects(); }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Projekt:" Width="140" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Projects, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedProject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Projects, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedProject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay binding is pointless. It has no effect, because it controls how a TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding updates the source property. Besides that, setting `Mode=OneWay` on the ItemsSource Binding and `Mode=TwoWay` on the SelectedItem Binding is redundant. These values are the default already.

Comment: The problem is the datacontext. The DataContext of the DataGrid is the ViewModel, but the context of the column is the object for that row. That's why the datagrid works, you define the columns and each item in the itemsSource becomes a row with that context, then the column can bind to properties of that item.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, you are right. I have just changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.Projects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```

The `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is the corresponding object in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`.

If your `Projects` collection is defined in the view model, you need to specify a `RelativeSource` for the binding to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the solution.